# why this date formatter not working correctly?

Tags: swift, calendar, nsdateformatter, dateformatter

facing the following issue:

I'm try to create a date by adding 2 strings one with a date "23/06/2023" and one is the time "21:00"

why I'm getting this strange result:

see my comment,

```
var final : Date {
        print("\(utcTime)") // ----time is correct 12:00
        let h = utcTime.prefix(2)
        let m = utcTime.suffix(2)
        let date : String = selectedDate.toUTCString()
        let cdate : String = date + " " + "\(h):\(m)" //---- string date is correctly composed 23/06/2023 12:00
        print(cdate)
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm"
        
        if let final = formatter.date(from: cdate){
            
            print(final) // why here i'm getting this strange date???  2022-12-19 04:00:00
            return final
        
        }
        
        return Date()
    }
```

Comment: What's your TimeZone? Are you at 6h diff from UTC?

Comment: Could you check with `print(final); print(final.description(with: .current))` what's the output for the second one?

Comment: Unrelated but why aren’t you using the variable utcTime directly?

Comment: Regarding the strange date, year is represented using lowercase y so use “dd/MM/yyyy”

Comment: yess.. the issue of the wrong date was the YYYY , thanks a lot